# Group Policy - Set IE11 as default on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-domain

In order to set the default Internet Browser in windows 8+ machines joined to a domain, using a GPO, you must configure the following:

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer\Set a default associations configurations file
```

This requires a file to be passed into it, which contains a list of extensions and default applications.
You can generate a file in the type required by running the following command:

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:C:\path\to\folder\file-associations.txt
```

If we have a look at this newly generated file, you will see it is laid out in a basic XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
   <Association Identifier=".bmp" ProgId="Paint.Picture" ApplicationName="Paint" />
   <Association Identifier=".dib" ProgId="Paint.Picture" ApplicationName="Paint" />
   <Association Identifier=".gif" ProgId="giffile" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" />
   <Association Identifier=".jfif" ProgId="pjpegfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".jpe" ProgId="jpegfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".jpeg" ProgId="jpegfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".jpg" ProgId="jpegfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".jxr" ProgId="wdpfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".png" ProgId="pngfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".tif" ProgId="TIFImage.Document" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".tiff" ProgId="TIFImage.Document" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier=".wdp" ProgId="wdpfile" ApplicationName="Photo Gallery Viewer" />
   <Association Identifier="http" ProgId="IE.HTTP" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" />
   <Association Identifier="https" ProgId="IE.HTTPS" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" />
</DefaultAssociations>
```

My question is this:

All I wish to set is the Default handler for HTTP and HTTPS, e.g. the Internet Browser, to Internet  Explorer 11.

If I edit this document to simply this (and save it as .xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
  <Association Identifier="http" ProgId="IE.HTTP" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" />
  <Association Identifier="https" ProgId="IE.HTTPS" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" />
</DefaultAssociations>
```

and then use this version of the file in the "Set a default associations configuration file" setting within the GPO, will it:

1. Simply change the default handlers for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols to IE, without touching the other default applications.

or

2. Wipe all of the other Default applications to factory default (or remove the associated programs all together) leaving only HTTP and HTTPS as the configured Protocols.

If anyone has done this before, I would appreciate an answer, as I'd rather not push a policy out across a massive corporate domain and potentially B0RK all of the users settings :)

Comment: Also - I will be testing this shortly on a single machine, so I will make sure to post the answer here should no one reply before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the file created by DISM.exe, removing all bar the HTTP and HTTPS protocols and using this as the file in the GPO has worked perfectly.

It has only changed the Default "Web Browser" to IE, and everything else has been left as it was.